# Silent registry changes on Windows 7

Tags: windows, windows-7, windows-registry, silent, user-settings

I apologize if this is listed elsewhere, but I truly couldn't find it.  Does anyone know how to silently modify registry keys in Windows 7?  I've tried running regedit with the /S command line switch, but it still prompts the user for permission to modify the keys before proceeding.  Any help would be much appreciated.

Andy

Comment: Please clarify the question. Are you trying to just run regedit without the UAC prompt, or are you pushing a .REG file to your users?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since you're talking Windows 7, you will probably have better luck using a PowerShell script to handle this.

http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd315394.aspx

`New Entry:
New-ItemProperty -Path HKLM:\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion -Name PowerShellPath -PropertyType String -Value $PSHome

New Key:
New-Item -Path Registry::HKCU_DeleteMe`

Microsoft makes sure that Regedit is noisy when it comes to importing registry keys. This is not true of other methods.

Comment: Didn't even think of PowerShell, can't imagine that not working for what I need to do.  This is why I hang out here.  Thanks guys!

Comment: Powershell should be fail at this command unless you run powershell in an elevated command prompt.  The message should be "New-ItemProperty : Requested registry access is not allowed"